# Safely Removing a Page in an Angular Application

Tags: angular

I am fairly new to Angular and was wondering what the safest way to remove a page in an Angular application would be?

What other dependencies should I be on the lookout for to ensure that the removal of said page does not interfere with the operation of the rest of the application.

Is there a simple way to see where in the code this page is referenced and what other components may be tied to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the component class for the page have a selector? Then you should search all of the HTML files in the project to determine where that selector is used.

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector:  'pm-products',
    templateUrl:  'app/products/product-list.component.html'
})
export  class  ProductListComponent  {
}
```

Some other component's template:

```
<div><h1>{{pageTitle}}<h1>
  <pm-products></pm-products>
</div>
```

If the component class has no selector, then it can only be accessed via routing. So check all of the routing throughout the application and ensure it is not defined in any routing configuration.

And you'll need to remove it from the declarations array in the Angular module it is declared in.